# I am using Angular 13 and sometimes the static content is not rendering, when I build the project and when I refresh the page its coming automatically

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using lazy loading functionality in my project and sometime when I build my project for first time and run it in my browser, I show that some content is missing only container is showing. And when I am refreshing the page or double tapping in my trackpad it coming again.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is static content it should load without any issue.

But I think you should try with change detection strategy

in constructor inject change detector

```
private cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
```

Use it after the content you want to show.

```
 this.cd.detectChanges();
```